# SQL Query select value if exist or create and pass

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to achieve the following in single SQL Query.
I am inserting values into table "A" for the columns "A1,A2".
I am passing the value for "A1" column directly.
For the column "A2", I need to select the "B2" column from "B" table and pass the value to "A2".
Incase if the "B" table does not contains the value for the condition which i am checking in my query, then i need to insert new row in "B" table and pass the B2 value to "A2".
My above query works well if the B table has value and condition matches.
I am not able to make it when the B table is not having/matching the value. Need help to insert new row and pass the newly inserted row to table A.

```
INSERT INTO A(A1,A2) VALUES('A1 Value',(select B2 from B where action = 'test'))
```

Comment: You can't insert into two tables in one query, this has to be at least 2 queries.

Comment: What do you want to insert when table B is not having/matching the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in one query, since you can only insert into one table at a time. So there's no way to insert a new row into `B` in the same query if the row is missing.

Assuming `action` has a unique index, you can do it in 2 queries like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO B (action, B2) VALUES ('test', 'default value');

INSERT INTO A (A1, A2) 
SELECT 'A1 Value', B2
FROM B
WHERE action = 'test';
```

`INSERT IGNORE` will do nothing if `action = 'test'` already exists.